# Return only needed values from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an Android messenger app. To do so, users sign up with phone number that are stored on **Firebase Realtime Database**.

To start texting someone, user should have, in his contacts, other signed up users on the DB.

To do that I have a method to retrieve contacts from user's phone and signedUp users on the DB.

```
private List<String> getContactsFromFirebase(final MyCallback myCallback){
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Users user = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                        assert user != null;
                        String contact_found = user.getPhone_number();
                        mContactsFromFirebase.add(contact_found);
                    }
                    myCallback.onCallback(mContactsFromFirebase);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
    return mContactsFromFirebase;

}
```

And compared users found on DB with user's contacts

```
private List<String> findSignedUpContacts(Map<String, String> contactsStored, List<String> firebaseNumbers) {

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String firebaseNumberKey : firebaseNumbers) {
        values.add(contactsStored.get(firebaseNumberKey));
    }
    return values;
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve from Firebase DB, only information regarding numbers stored in the list created above(numbers that match across DB & contacts) and display the result in a **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter**.

How can I please do that?

Here is my DB structure.

```
Users
    5AWIQqYkdoZwFBqM0YrvZiqBj633
        image: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cha..."
        name:  "Plasita"
        phone_number: "+50940404200"
        status: "Coding is my life.."
        thumbnail: "Default"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there is no machanism in Firebase to query by a list, you'd need to run through the list and query each element, which is very inefficient. What I recommend is: as you're already bringing all elements from the "Users" node, store them in a secondary data structure and filter that.

```
 for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      Users user = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
      assert user != null;
      String contact_found = user.getPhone_number();
      mContactsFromFirebase.add(user);//this data structure now takes users

  }



private List<User> findSignedUpContacts(Map<String, String> contactsStored, List<User> firebaseUsers) {

    List<User> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User user : firebaseUsers) {
        if(contactsStored.containsKey(user.getPhone_number()) 
        {
            values.add(user);
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

Now values have the data about the users that are matched with the ones in your phone.

Comment: Ok I get it, so you're recommending using my own RecyclerView with the values that I stored instead of FirebaseRecyclerView?

Comment: Yeah, You'd need a query to use the FirebaseRecyclerView, but you can't use one single query to retrieve all the values you want. So yes, you'll need to implement your own RecyclerView

Comment: glad to help :)